# While Loop not looping when condition is not true C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# console program as part of my assignment. What I am trying to do here is to display the message each time when the user enters something invalid. However when I type in something invalid after making the right choice it only displays the error message once. After the message I make a valid selection and then an invalid selection it exits the console. I also want it to display the right message whenever the user inputs valid numbers but that does not happen continuously after making an invalid selection. It just exits the console... I tried using "||" instead of "&&" which does not work at all.

I am an absolute Beginner in programming so if there is anything I am doing wrong please help me with it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
        uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (uI != 1 && uI != 2 && uI != 3 && uI != 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SELECT 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
            uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        if (uI == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("msg");
            Console.WriteLine("SELECT 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
            uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        if (uI == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("msgg");
            Console.WriteLine("SELECT 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
            uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        if (uI == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("msggg");
            Console.WriteLine("SELECT 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
            uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        if (uI == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("msgggg");
            Console.WriteLine("SELECT 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
            uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think this will keep looping? Where is your outer control loop? Think about it again and reapproach the problem. You need a loop encompasing it all to indicate when to exit the program.

Comment: @Brendan I thought this would keep looping because that's how my tutor taught us

Comment: Your code should not have the same command (`int.Parse()`) in multiple location. This is an indication that a loop needs to be used for repeated operations.

Comment: @ja72 so uI = Console.ReadLine(); would have been fine?

Comment: @Yasin no. The point I made was you do not need many `ReadLine()` statements in your program. Only one in the beggining of the loop would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an infinitive loop. Moreover I'd use a switch case which is more readable:

```
Console.WriteLine( "Enter 1, 2, 3, OR 4" );

while( true ) {
   uI = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine( ) );

   string message = "Error";
   switch( uI ) {
      case 1: message = "msg"; break;
      case 2: message = "msgg"; break;
      case 3: message = "msggg"; break;
      case 4: message = "msgggg"; break;
      default: break;
   }

   Console.WriteLine( message );      
   Console.WriteLine( "SELECT 1, 2, 3, OR 4" );
}
```

Comment: The operator works fine but it doesn't always loop back to the code for when the condition is false

Comment: You also need the `if()` statements within the loop.

Comment: I would also put one `Writeline()` before the `ReadLine()`. There is non _need_ to repeat commands.

Comment: @Fuex This is more shorthand compared to mine and I can understand it too. Thank you

Comment: @Fuex Thank you Once again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SELECT 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
            var uI=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (uI==1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("msg");
            } else if (uI==2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("msgg");
            }
            else if (uI==3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("msggg");
            }
            else if (uI==4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("msgggg");
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

So the program takes an input and acts upon it, unless it is not 1,2,3, or 4 where it exists the loop with the `break;` statement.

Comment: that seems abit advanced for me as I also have to comment showing my understanding. I won't be able to annotate that

Comment: It uses the same commands (except break) as your code. Imagine you are the computer stepping through the code line by line. What do you do and why? This is how you figure out how to program. Essentially the steps are a) Get Input, b) Process Input, c) If Input is expected act on input and d) Otherwise exit.

Comment: thank you for explaining it, I will use that method to try to understand and annotate :)

Comment: Process input is assigning the input as a value to a variable, in this case it is from user to uI. Just one issue, if the input is not as expected, I need to display an error message so instead of exiting it will be
    Console.WriteLine("ERRORMSG");

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
        uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while(uI > 0) //exit loop if 0 is entered
        {
           switch(uI)
           {
              case 1: Console.WriteLine("msg"); break;
              case 2: Console.WriteLine("msgg"); break;
              case 3: Console.WriteLine("msggg"); break;
              case 4: Console.WriteLine("msgggg"); break;
              default: break; //do not write to console just loop again

           }
           Console.WriteLine("Enter 1, 2, 3, OR 4");
           uI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you , I can only use that after gaining an understanding of switch and case which I am working on now so I can use it :)